# Help calculating the terms of the following generating function?

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

I have generating function $$\dfrac{x^5(1-x^3)}{(1-x)^2(1-x^4)}$$

Starting with $$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 +x + x^2 + x^3...$$

$$\frac{x^5}{1-x} = x^5 + x^6 + x^7+...$$

Now if I try to multiply $(1-x^3)$ or $\frac{1}{1-x^4}$, its going to get really messy. Is it necessary to do each step like this or is there a quicker way to get the terms? They turn out to be

$$x^5 + 2x^6 + 3x^7 + 3x^8 + 4x^9 +...$$

Comment: Yiu could try partial fractions.

Answer (score 3):

$${x^5(1-x^3)\over(1-x)^2(1-x^4)}=x^5(1-x^3)(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots)(1+x^4+x^8+x^{12}+\cdots)$$

$$=x^5(1-x^3)(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+6x^4+8x^5+10x^6+12x^7+15x^8+\cdots)$$

$$=x^5(1+2x+3x^2+3x^3+4x^4+5x^5+6x^6+6x^7+7x^8+\cdots)$$

$$=x^5+2x^6+3x^7+3x^8+4x^9+5x^{10}+6x^{11}+6x^{12}+7x^{13}+\cdots$$

Comment: $=\sum_nx^n(n-3-\lfloor n/4\rfloor)$

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to derive a recursion from the generating function.  Let's say
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$
and
$$f(x) = \frac{x^5(1-x^3)}{(1-x)^2 (1-x^4)}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
(1-x)^2 (1-x^4)  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n &= x^5(1-x^3) \\
(1-2 x+x^2-x^4+2 x^5-x^6)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n &= x^5 - x^8
\end{align}$$
We see by examination of this last equation that $a_n = 0$ for $0 \le n \le 4$, and $a_5=1$.  (Start with $a_0$, then find $a_1$, then $a_2$, etc.) For $n \ge 6$, the coefficient of $x^n$ on the LHS is $a_n-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-4}+2a_{n-5}-a_{n-6}$ and on the RHS is $-\delta_{n8}$, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.  So for $n \ge 6$,
$$a_n =2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-4}-2a_{n-5}+a_{n-6} -\delta_{n8}$$
Using this recursion combined with the boundary conditions, we can generate as many values of $a_n$ as we like.